# Vue.js - v-model binding a hidden input

Tags: jquery, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, jquery-events

I have the following hidden input:

```
 <input id="myHiddenInput" 
    name="myHiddenInput" 
    type="hidden" 
    v-model="comment.myHiddenInput" 
    v-on:change="comment.myHiddenInput=$event.target.value">

var app = new Vue({
   el: '#app',
   data: {
     comment: {'myHiddenInput': ''}
   }
})
```

In my javascript fucntion I set the hidden value and trigger a change event as follows:

```
var myFunction = function () {

   $('#myHiddenInput').val(JSON.stringify(hiddentStuff)).trigger('change');

};
```

However the above doesn't work i.e. the two way binding does not work.

But if I do this it works:

```
var myFunction = function () {

   $('#myHiddenInput').val(JSON.stringify(hiddentStuff)).trigger('change');
   document.getElementById('myHiddenInput').dispatchEvent(new Event('change'));

};
```

Why is `.trigger('change')` not sufficient on its own, why do i need to call`dispatchEvent(new Event('change'))` aswell ?

Comment: Because jQuery uses it's own event system, and Vue works with DOM events. And as mentioned in the last question, using `app` to set the value directly would be better. https://codepen.io/Kradek/pen/pdxWzg?editors=1010

Answer (score 0):

You can use local browsers variables with Js when You use jquery and vue.js

Answer (score -1):

I would advice to not use jquery in this way together with Vue.

Try to change the binded object the vue way instead:

```
this.comment.myHiddenInput = JSON.stringify(hiddentStuff); //Your new value here
```

This will automatically update the input and also trigger the change.